# How does writing data from spark to vertica work?

Tags: python, apache-spark, vertica

Are there any good online resources to learn how writing data from Spark to Vertica works? I'm trying to understand why writing to a Vertica database is slow.

This is my basic workflow:

1. Create a SparkContext. I'm using the class pyspark.sql.SQLContext to create one.
2. From SQLContext, using the read method to get DataFrameReader interface under 'jdbc' format.

   df = self._sqlContext.read.format('jdbc').options(url=self._jdbcURL, dbtable=subquery).load()

   Read entries from a Vertica database using jdbc connection (call it dbA)
3. Write those entries into another Vertica database using the SparkContext in Step 1 (call it dbB)

Right now it's just a simple read from dbA and write to dbB. But writing 50 entries takes about 5 seconds.

Thanks!

Comment: To answer your question, we need to know what you've tried.

Comment: I've updated my question with more details. I'm looking for general reference material.

Comment: My general reference would be to use an ETL product such as Talend.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I want to learn more about the Spark to Vertica connection and porting of data.

Comment: There is no Spark to Vertica connection. Unless you know what you're doing, you're not going to run Spark standalone.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried HPE's Big Data Marketplace, specifically the [HPE Vertica Connector For Apache Spark](https://saas.hpe.com/marketplace/big-data/hpe-vertica-connector-apache-spark)?  You'll need to create an account to download the file, but there's no cost associated with creating an account. The documentation includes a Scala example of writing a Spark data frame to a Vertica table.